# Can I call a method in a class annotation in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a class called `AllTests` with the annotation `@SuiteClasses`.

```java
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    StorageTest.class,
        ...
})
public class AllTests
{
   ...
}
```

Because i want to reuse the list of `SuiteClasses` (Array of `Class<?>`), i want to create the array dynamically in a method and return it. Is it possible to call this method directly in a annotation? Something like this:

```java
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@SuiteClasses(AllTests.getAllMyRelevantClasses())
public class AllTests
{
   public static Class<?>[] getAllMyRelevantClasses() {
      return new Class[]{
         StorageTest.class,
         ...};
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, possible. Are you getting some error?

Comment: yes, i get `The value for annotation attribute Suite.SuiteClasses.value must be a class literal`